# How can I add tags to another user question without having to edit its message?

Tags: support, tags, edits, suggested-edits

I've tried editing another user's original question to add a tag that I felt was missing. But it asks me to edit at least 6 characters.

Is there no way to add or suggest additional tags to a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not until you've acquired more than 2,000 reputation on that site (after which you do not earn any reputation for making question edits), no.

This restriction was, I believe, added to prevent multiple question edits by sub 2,000 reputation users where only tags were changed.

Very many questions where tags need to be changed can also be improved by altering the question body and the title: so I conject this is not seen to be an overly onerous restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity itself: suggest *nothing but* tag edits. If you do that, the edit will go through ([example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/16827)). I think you can also make edits to the title, as any title edits are always enough.

However, if you make even a one-character edit to the body, you'll have to edit at least six characters. That's kind of buggy, but there it is.

Comment: I think that's because you have advanced edit rights. I just tested again and even by changing only tag, I get the 6 characters error message.

Comment: @TheBakker: Nope, on that site I have only 300-some rep. Nowhere near enough to make edits without review, and as far as I know that's the only privilege these days that changes anything about edits besides the ability to make CW edits at 100.

Comment: Hum, is it possible that the limit is different on stackoverflow ? That's where I did my tests.

Comment: @TheBakker: I've made hundreds of suggestions there, quite a few of which only changed tags, and although I do have 2k on SO now, I don't think anything's changed….

Comment: @TheBakker: Well, OK, at least [three](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6339347) [of them](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7773563) [changed only tags](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9472080). That's quite a few, right? ;)

Comment: Hehe thanks, not sure what to say, even without touching the textarea it gives me the error ;)